# Simulate with a click event - not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I was able to find this script and tweak it to my need. However, it seems to work on all browsers tested except IE11.   I am loading this via GTM. Any ideas?

```
 var simulateClick = function (elem) {
    // Create our event (with options)
    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
    });
    // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
    var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
  simulateClick(document.getElementById('vshow.registration.regForm.loginLink'));
```

Comment: It's useful to get familiar with the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#Browser_compatibility) ... "_MouseEvent constructor: Internet Explorer NO_"

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#Polyfill) should solve your problem